# Making a node module with js_of_ocaml

Tags: node.js, module, ocaml, commonjs, js-of-ocaml

The [js_of_ocaml documentation](https://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/3.1.0/manual/rev-bindings) says about making a Node.js module:

> Js.export and Js.export_all will export a value to module.exports if it exists.

What I'm confused about is the "if it exists" part. How do I make sure that the module def exists? i.e. if I'm making an OCaml  library that I'd like to be able to import from JavaScript (TypeScript actually), how can I make sure that I get such a module as the output of `js_of_ocaml`?

Answer (score 0):

If `module.exports` exists, a value is exported as node module.
And if `module.exports` doesn't exists (on web browser for example), a value is exported as global variable.

Comment: Right, but how do I make "module.exports" exist in the generated JS code?

Comment: node.js (or other runtime) prepares "module.exports". For web browser, a module bundler like browserify, rollup or webpack is needed.